# Radio button not deselecting in radiogroup because of wrapper element

Tags: html, vue.js, pug

I have created a component for radio buttons with custom styling and would like to group them. However when i use a v-for to render multiple radio buttons they do not deselect when another radio option has been selected.

The template of my radio button component looks like this:

```html
<template lang="pug">
label(:for="input.name")
  input(
    :value="input.value"
    type="radio"
    :name="input.name"
    hidden
  )
  .radio-wrapper(
    @click="handleInput()"
    :class="{'active-check': input.value}"
  )
    .circle
      Icon(icon="checkWhite")
    |{{ input.label }}
</template>
```

I know its because of the `label` but i can't remove it because i need a wrapper for the input and the `.radio-wrapper` element because my version of nuxt doesn't allow multiple root elements.

I can't really use nuxt 3 right now so anyone know a different solution?

Answer (score 0):

The [v-for](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/list.html) syntax is off.  It should be given an array and has similar syntax to a [for..in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) loop

```
label(v-for="input in inputs")
    input(
      v-model="inputSelection"
      :value="input.value"
      type="radio"
      :name="input.name"
    )
```

Also, [radio inputs in Vue](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/forms.html#radio) all need the exact same v-model to be considered a group.

```js
data: {
    inputSelection: '',  // v-model value
    inputs: [...] // array of input objects
}
```

[example codepen](https://codepen.io/yoduh/pen/rNqqogz)
(I'm not sure what exact purpose `radio-wrapper` serves so I did not implement it.)